# How do I delete all comments from a specific old blog post?

Tags: comments

I'm cleaning up an old, controversial blog entry and I need to remove all the comments from the post.

Surprisingly, I can't find a way to do this within the existing WordPress (3.0.4) UI.

I can certainly go through and click "trash" on all 200+ comments, but that seems.. excessive. Is there another way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternative for people reading this with a fear for SQL............... (or finding this via Google after Januari 2011):

Wait for this action until 3.1 comes out, then go to a post, check all comments and bulk "move to trash" :) (it should come out any day now) (http://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/)

(or download 3.1 RC3 from http://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/)

#### Example:

http://edward.de.leau.net/files/bulkremove.png

Answer (score 5):

WordPress doesn't support bulk management of comments on a post by post basis. Although it does have a comment management section directly at the post's edit page. As you said, you would have to click on "Trash" on every single comment:

[image]

Alternately you could take a back up of the wp_comments and wp_commentmeta table and run the following queries:

1. Find post ID. Lets say the relevant id is X.

   ```
   SELECT ID from wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_title='Hello world!' INTO @x;
   ```
2. Add relevant comment metadata just to preserve integrity:

   ```
   INSERT INTO wp_commentmeta (comment_id, meta_key, meta_value) SELECT comment_ID, "wp_trash_meta_time", UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID=@x;

   INSERT INTO wp_commentmeta (comment_id, meta_key, meta_value) SELECT comment_ID, "wp_trash_meta_status",comment_approved FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID=@x;
   ```
3. Trash all comments:

   ```
   UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_approved='trash' WHERE comment_post_ID=@x;
   ```

Comment: excellent answer -- out of curiosity how traumatic is it if the comment metadata isn't inserted? What breaks, if anything?

Comment: I've not been able to find a big differene except that the trashed comments won't be deleted after the EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS days. (wp-includes/default-constants.php). If you untrash them their approval status will default to "unapproved".

Comment: I assume you should execute step 3 before step 2 if you really want to keep the old approval status? Now they would be set to `trash` in step 2, and then we copy this `trash` status in step 3, not the previous status.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for pointing it out, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Hi **@Jeff Atwood:**

I'm assuming you have MySQL query access. This will give you all comments for your blog post whose URL slug is `'your-blog-post'` *(the slug is the last segment in your post's URL if you are using pretty permalinks, i.e. for http://example.com/2011/01/foo-bar-baz/ your slug would be `'foo-bar-baz'`):*

```
SELECT * from wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='your-post-slug'
)
```

And this will give you all the comment metadata:

```
SELECT * from wp_commentmeta WHERE comment_id IN (
  SELECT comment_ID from wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID IN (
    SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='your-post-slug'
  )
)
```

So... run these two commands (but be sure to replace the post_name value to be equal to yours):

```
DELETE from wp_commentmeta WHERE comment_id IN (
  SELECT comment_ID from wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID IN (
    SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='your-post-slug'
  )
);

DELETE from wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='your-post-slug'
);
```

P.S. This will of course fully delete them but unless you do want to keep them in the trash this is easier than moving them to the trash.

Answer (score 3):

I do not advise removing directly from the database as data may have dependencies one might end up with orphan records.

With the post ID (add it in `ADDPOSTID`), save the script bellow and add the PHP file in the root of your WordPress website, login as Admin and call the file directly on your browser:

```
<?php

require('./wp-load.php');

if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    if ( $comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => ADDPOSTID ) ) ) {
        foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
            echo '<p>Deleting comment '.$comment->comment_ID.'</p>';
            wp_delete_comment( $comment->comment_ID, true );
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>No comments found</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Not allowed</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the best solution **if** you can install [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) on the server would be using it this way:

```
$ wp comment delete $(wp comment list --post_id={ID})
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not enough, you must also update the column count, otherwise it will not be displayed correctly.
Here is a sample code for a multisite install.

```
try 
{   
    $rowsUpdated = $wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "COMMENTS SET COMMENT_APPROVED='trash' 
    WHERE comment_post_id = " . $post_id
    );
    if ( $rowsUpdated != 0 ) {
        $wpdb->query( 
            "
            UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "POSTS SET COMMENT_COUNT = COMMENT_COUNT - " .  $rowsUpdated . "
            WHERE ID = " . $post_id
        );
    }
}       
catch (Exception $e) 
{ 
    echo( 'Unexpected error while trying to connect to WP database: ' . $e->getMessage() );
}
```