# Delete all one-word comments

Tags: comments, mysql, hacks, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to delete all wordpress comments with only one word. I found this mysql query to delete all comments at once, but that's not what I want to achieve:

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER : Not a WordPress Developer, Just a MySQL DBA

If you have privileges to login to MySQL and query data you could collect all the `comment_ID` values that have one word.

```
SELECT comment_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE
REPLACE(TRIM(comment_content),' ','')=TRIM(comment_content);
```

You can test this by also seeing the comment_content

```
SELECT comment_ID,comment_content FROM wp_comments WHERE
REPLACE(TRIM(comment_content),' ','')=TRIM(comment_content);
```

Using the WordPress API, retrieve those `comment_ID` values and delete them.

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

Other posts have been given for bulk deleting of comments (none of these are my posts):

- [How do I delete all comments from a specific old blog post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/how-do-i-delete-all-comments-from-a-specific-old-blog-post?rq=1)
- [How to Delete Old Comments by Date?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15870/how-to-delete-old-comments-by-date?rq=1)
- [SQL query to delete comments older than 90 days?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15554/sql-query-to-delete-comments-older-than-90-days?rq=1)